# What exactly is an "induced operation"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

Examples of places where I see this used:

> Let * be a binary operation in *S* and let *H* be a subset of *S*... the binary operation on *H* given by restricting * to *H* is the **induced operation** of * on *H*
>
> For a subgroup, it is not sufficient that "the set of one group be a subset of another, but also that the group operation on the subset be the *induced operation* that assigns the same element to each ordered pair from this subset as is assigned by the group operation on the whole set"

I just really don't understand what an induced operation is supposed to be.

Is this an accurate understanding?: If you have the binary structure $\langle S,* \rangle$, then the induced operation is if you make another binary structure with set *S'* and let the operation be the same * as in the first binary structure. In other words, is it accurate to say that the operation * in the binary structure $\langle S',* \rangle$ is the induced operation of $\langle S,* \rangle$, but the operation *' in $\langle S',*' \rangle$ is not?

All quotes from the book "A First Course in Abstract Algebra" by John Fraleigh, 7th edition

Comment: What is $S'$ in your question?

Comment: S' would be any set that's not equal to set S

Comment: Then it does not mean anything to "let the operation be the same as in the first binary structure". There needs to be a link between two sets to compare the operations.

Comment: @CaptainLama what do you mean by that?

Comment: Consider $S=\mathbb{Z}$, with operation the addition. Now take $S'$ the set of the 45 most common first names in Argentina. What does it mean that an operation on $S'$ is "the same" as the addition on $S$? When $S'\subset S$, "being the same" means that the operation on $S'$ is the restriction of the operation on $S$ (see my answer for an example and a counter-example). But if $S$ and $S'$ are just unrelated sets this does not make sense anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suggestion is correct, except that you forgot to say what $S'$ has to do with $S$. And it is this: $S'$ is a subset of $S$. For instance, sum on $\mathbb R$ does *not* induce an operation in $(-1,1)$ since, in general the sum of two elements of $(-1,1)$ is not an element of $(-1,1)$.

There is another case of induced operations, which appears in the context of quotients of algebraic structures, but I don't know whether or not you are familar with this.

Answer (score 4):

I think looking at an example is quite telling: let us consider $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{R}$. Then $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are groups for the usual addition. But $\mathbb{Q}$ is also a group for the (quite arbitrary) operation $a\star b= a+b+1$.

Now the addition on $\mathbb{Q}$ is the operation induced by the addition on $\mathbb{R}$, meaning that if you take two elements $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$, you can add them as real numbers or as rational numbers, and it is the same thing.

On the other hand, even though $(\mathbb{Q},\star)$ is a group and $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{R}$, the operation $\star$ is not the restriction of the addition on $\mathbb{R}$, it is not the induced operation, so this does not define a subgroup.

On the other hand, if we define $a\bullet b= a+ b+1$ on $\mathbb{R}$, then $\star$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ *is* the restriction of $\bullet$ on $\mathbb{R}$, so $(\mathbb{Q},\star)$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{R},\bullet)$.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thank you! Would you be able to say "(Q,⋆) is a subgroup of (R,⋆)"?

Comment: If you define $a\star b= 2(a+b)$ on $\mathbb{R}$, then yes.

Comment: I fail to see how $a\star b$ makes a group. What would be the neutral element of that group?

Comment: So you say that $2(0+b)=b$ for all  $b\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: No no, I'm just saying nonsense. I'm not sure what I was thinking... Anyway this does not change the point about induced operations.

Comment: @CaptainLama: Sure. Just define e.g. $a\star b=a+b-2$ and everything is fine (the neutral element then is $2$, and the inverse of $a$ is $4-a$

Comment: Yes, obviously, the correct thing to do is to take any bijection $f: \mathbb{Q}\to A$ to some group $A$, which is *not* a group morphism, and transport the group structure on $A$. I guess I'm tired!

Comment: I edited to make it correct.

Answer (score 0):

> Induced operation. **Definition (2.4)** Let $\ast$ be a binary operation on a set $S$ and let $H$ be a subset of $S$. If for all $a,b \in H$ we also have $a\ast b \in H$, then $H$ is closed under $\ast$. In this case, the binary operation on $H$ given by restricting $\ast$ to $H$ is the induced operation of $\ast$ on $H$.

The above is quoted from [Section 2 – Binary Operations
Instructor: Yifan Yang
Fall 2006](http://jupiter.math.nctu.edu.tw/~weng/courses/alg_2007/Algebra%25202006/Handout-Section2.pdf) the first result on google search for induced binary operation.

My understanding would be it induces a new magma ( a set with an operation it's closed under) which if it has certain elements would be a subgroup, subring, etc.